# Python Multiprocessing returning results with Logging and running frozen on Windows

Tags: python, windows, logging, multiprocessing

I need some help with implementing logging while multiprocessing and running the application frozen under Windows. There are dozens of topics on this subject and I have spent a lot of time reviewing and testing those. I have also extensively reviewed [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes), but I cannot figure out how to implement this in my code.

I have created a minimum example which runs fine on Linux, but crashes on Windows (even when not frozen). The example I created is just one of many iterations I have put my code through.

You can find the [minimum example on github](https://github.com/1marc1/pymp). Any assistance to get this example working would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Marc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The basic

On Linux, a child process is created by `fork` method by default. That means, the child process inherits almost everything from the parent process.

On Windows, the child process is created by `spawn` method.
That means, a child process is started almost from crash, re-imports and re-executes any code that is outside of the guard cloud `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

### Why it worked or failed

On Linux, because the `logger` object is inherited, your program will start logging.
But it is far from perfect since you log directly to the file.
Sooner or later, log lines will be overlapped or `IO` error on file happens due to race condition between processes.

On Windows, since you didn't pass the `logger` object to the child process, and it re-imports your `pymp_global` module, `logger` is a `None` object. So when you try logging with a `None` object, it crashes for sure.

### The solution

Logging with multiprocessing is not an easy task.
For it to work on Windows, you must either pass a logger object to child processes and/or log with `QueueHandler`. Another similar solution for inter-process communication is to use `SocketHandler`.

The idea is that only one thread or process does the logging. Other processes just send the log records. This prevents the race condition and ensures the log is written out after the critical process got time to do its job.

So how to implement it? 
I have encountered this logging problem before and already written the code. 
You can just use it with [logger-tt](https://github.com/Dragon2fly/logger_tt) package.

```
#pymp.py
from logging import getLogger
from logger_tt import setup_logging    

setup_logging(use_multiprocessing=True)
logger = getLogger(__name__)
# other code below
```

For other modules

```
#pymp_common.py
from logging import getLogger

logger = getLogger(__name__)
# other code below
```

This saves you from writing all the logging config code everywhere manually.
You may consider changing the `log_config` [file](https://github.com/Dragon2fly/logger_tt#sample-config) to suit your need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am busy testing things out. Once I have tested everything I will get back and let you know how it went.

Comment: This is awesome! I have been playing around with logger-tt and have tested it extensively. I can certainly recommend this package!

Comment: @Marc Thanks.If this answer helped, you can mark it as `accepted`.

Comment: We are now nearly 2.5 years later and logger_tt has worked very well. I am in a situation whereby I have created a second application for which I also want to use logging. So, I set it up in a similar way, just using a different log file; called app2.log.

What happens is that while the first application is running (and logging to app1.log), when I run the second application, the logs end up in app1.log. When I close the first application and run the second one, the logs for the second application go to app2.log, as they should. This behaviour only happens on Windows. Any ideas?

Comment: hi @Marc Could you create an issue [here](https://github.com/Dragon2fly/logger_tt/issues) with more details? I suspect you didn't config the port differently for the second app. But it could be anything else.

Comment: Thank you! I have created [an issue](https://github.com/Dragon2fly/logger_tt/issues/21).